# Escuchar cambios en react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> Vengo del desarrollo en Angular y hay cosas que quiero replicar y no sabría.

Tengo un componente snack/toast que lo puse en el app, el cual debería mostrarse en ciertos casos con un mensaje custom.

Lo que necesito es disparar alguna "acción" desde otro punto de la aplicación, desde algún componente por ejemplo y que este componente snackbar que está puesto en la app escuche ese cambio o ese evento y se muestre.

En Angular, lo haría con un service con un observable y me subscribo a esos cambios. Pero esta programación reactiva tengo entendido que no está en react native. No sé cómo podría hacerlo.

**App.tsx**

```
    export default function App() {

      // TOAST 
      const [toastVisible, setToastVisible] = useState(false);
      const onToggleSnackBar = () => setToastVisible(true);
      const onDismissSnackBar = () => setToastVisible(false);

      const [toastMessage, setToastMessage] = useState<string>('');
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <StatusBar style="light" />

          {/* Toast Error Component */}
          <Snackbar
            visible={toastVisible}
            onDismiss={onDismissSnackBar}
            action={{label: 'close',onPress: () => {}}}>{toastMessage}
          </Snackbar>
       
        </NavigationContainer>
       
      );
    }
```

Lo que necesito entonces, es desde otra pantalla, pongámosle de nombre "componente 2" disparar algo y que este componente lo escuche.

**Componente2 tsx**

```
    manageError(){
      const mensajeError = "Este es un mensaje de prueba"
      // Disparar evento y mostrar componente

      
    }
```

El componente 2, está en otra parte de la aplicación, es el que debería disparar este evento para que el componente que está en app, se muestre.
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Si entendí bien quieres que el snackbar se muestre dependiendo de la acción que se ejecute en algún otro componente?

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux exacto. Eso mismo, pero no se como hacerlo en react, en angular haria un subject y me subscribo. Pero aca ni idea

Answer (score 1):

El flujo de datos en react-native es unidireccional y es descendente. Es decir, el flujo de los datos va del componente padre al componente hijo a través de las props.

Pero... la situación que planteas es muy válida, a veces necesitamos compartir datos entre componentes que se encuentran en niveles muy diferentes en el árbol de components. Y en estos casos, puedes usar `Context`.

Por ejemplo, siguiendo con tu caso del `Snackbar`...

**Primero** necesitarías crear un provider que te brinde el acceso al status actual del snackbar (visible o no) y a unos métodos que te permitan cambiar su status.

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';

interface ISnackbarContext {
  visible: boolean;
  message?: string;
  showSnackbar: (message: string) => void;
  hideSnackbar: () => void;
}

const defaultContext: ISnackbarContext = {
  visible: false,
  showSnackbar: () => {},
  hideSnackbar: () => {},
};

export const SnackbarContext = createContext<ISnackbarContext>(defaultContext);

export const SnackbarProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<ISnackbarContext>(defaultContext);

  const displaySnackbar = (message: string) => {
    setState({...state, visible: true, message});
  };

  const removeSnackbar = () => {
    setState({...state, visible: false});
  };

  return (
    <SnackbarContext.Provider
      value={{
        showSnackbar: displaySnackbar,
        hideSnackbar: removeSnackbar,
        visible: state.visible,
      }}>
      {children}
    </SnackbarContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Segundo**, el provider debe englobar todos los componentes que quieres que tengan acceso al status de tu snackbar. En este caso creo que tu necesitarías englobar toda tu aplicación si quieres actualizar el status del snack-bar desde cualquier parte de tu app. Por ejemplo lo puedes poner en el índex.

```
const Application = () => {
  return (
    <SnackbarProvider>
      <App />
    </SnackbarProvider>
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Application);
```

Y por ultimo, lo único que necesitas es acceder al context creado en los componentes donde lo necesites usando el hook `useContext`.

```
export default function App() {
  const context = useContext(SnackbarContext);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar style="light" />
        {/* Toast Error Component */}
        <Snackbar
          visible={context.visible}
          onDismiss={() => context.hideSnackbar()}
          action={{label: 'close', onPress: () => {}}}>
          {context.message}
        </Snackbar>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Lo mismo seria para mostrar u ocultar el snackbar desde cualquier otro componente, solo necesitas importar el context y ejecutar el método que necesites (showSnackbar o hideSnackbar)

```
const MyCustomComponent = () => {
  const context = useContext(SnackbarContext);

  const displayError = () => {
    context.showSnackbar('Este es un error de ejemplo');
  };
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container]}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={displayError}>
        <Text>Show Snackbar</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Espero que esta info te sirva de ayuda, Context realmente es muy útil en muchos casos, pero te recomiendo leer este apartado para entenderlo mejor y saber cuando NO utilizarlo, pues puede resultar en un dolor de cabeza cuando quieres reutilizar tus componentes.

https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper